# Django-filter is being ignored when query parameter value is non-existing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

Code where problem occurs:

```
class GameFilter(FilterSet):
    release = MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=Game.RELEASE_CHOICES, method='release_filter', widget=CSVWidget, required=True)
  
    def release_filter(self, queryset, name, releases):
        if releases:
            ...
        return queryset
```

Lets say in my `Game.RELEASE_CHOICES`, one of my options is "2", this means this query is working for me
http://localhost:8000/games/?release=2

In this case I **can reach my breakpoint** in `release_filter` method.

**BUT**

When I try to query this URL with non existing query parameter value

http://localhost:8000/games/?release=2156

The `release_filter` is not being executed, **cant reach breakpoint** at all and all I get in return is:

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "results": [],
    "page_size": 20
}
```

What I would like to achieve is the filter being executed despite of non existing query parameter value. Is it possible? Thank you for all possible answers.

Comment: why do you need if condition? you have set releases as required field anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
releases = request.GET.get('release',None)
# if using DRF
# releases = request.query_params.get('release',None)
if releases and releases in dict(Game.RELEASE_CHOICES).keys():
    ...
return queryset
```